# Communication between web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

How can I communicate between web applications?

I have an application that manages my web application with other applications: When I login to my application, it lets me connect to another application. 
I work in VS2015 ASP.net MVC, c#. Help, please!

Comment: Maybe websocket? need more specific information to answer...

Comment: The same way a *browser* communicates with a web application - using an HTTP API. A web service/microservice/API is just a web application whose endpoints behave a certain way. Create the endpoints you want and call them from other applications the same way you'd call any other service

Comment: i have 3 web applications that are already created and i develop an application to manage  between applications and users so if the user authentify in the my applications it can login to the others directly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean here by communication.

it can have two meanings -

**Page Re-directions from one web app to another:**

You want the links of other applications to be included in one application and then when user clicks they can redirect users to those respective pages.  If you have SSO implemented, they will not even ask the login information.

This would be simple, you have to include anchor tags with targets of other web sites.

- As long as they are hosted under same domain name, it would work.
- If they are not hosted in same domain name, then you will have to enable CORS in those web sites to allow requests from other origins.

**Secondly, by communication, you may mean to just call APIs to get some data in current web app**

For this you will have to write the RESTful APIs from other applications which cater to your needs.

Then you can call those APIs like any other web API call.

Here also, if the other applications / APIs are not hosted under same domain name, you will have to enable CORS.

For enabling CORS in your application, please [refer this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

For creating APIs, you can [refer this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Again, this is not directly answers to your question. But I am sure this has provided enough details to think about integrating with other apps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks; but how to connect two websites with webservice!!

Comment: If you want only some of the data from other website, you can add .Net REST api and then your other site can call that API to get data.

Comment: if the user connect on the first website then he can connect directly to the other websites without reconnect